# Maintain EBS data in sync

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, wordpress, synchronization

I'm here again! On my last questions here I was wondering how to sync data on EBS.

Ok. I've tested in first time the **NFS**, but everything goes extremely SLOW! And its a shared volume, if the master machine goes down, the others goes down too. Ok, I don't want NFS. Dicarted.

Now It's **GlusterFS**. I configured everything right, but I discovered that I can't use only two servers to sync files - I need a client too. Ok, I don't need this too, because like I said, if the masters servers goes down the clients will fail. Discarted.

Elastic Beanstalk on Amazon: **I LOVED IT! REALLY!** But don't have in Brazil and don't support spot instances... Discarted.

Rsync was my last option and works like I want, but I have a problem: if the files on client be modified? I host my images on S3 and my MySQL is on another cloud, so this is not the problem. I use Wordpress, so let's supose I'm on Webserver2 and I install/configure/update a plugin. The data will be save on Webserver2 but the rsync only run on Webserver1 to the others! So the configuration will be ignored on the others instances.

I can configure mod_proxy or whatever like this to server wp-admin to server 1. But if the server 1 goes down, no one can access the wp-admin...

So I have a big problem here. How I can solve this problem? I was thinking if I can host my PHP files on S3 and update/save/get automatically by some configuration on my machine. I really don't know what to do and I will be very happy if someone can help me.

I'm want to make this configuration because I have a really busy web blog, and I don't want to depend on only cloud for hanging all connections. How big sites works with this? Like Foursquare, Pinterest and *Instagram*?! Someone knows how they organize the structure?

Thank you! And sorry for my really poor english.

Comment: With glusterfs it is my understanding that you can run a server and a client on the same machine so you could run the same on each server and they are replicates of each other (however I have no 1st hand experience with this).

Are you running 2 servers for redundancy or because you get so much traffic that a single server can't handle it?

Comment: You ask parenthetically about infrastructure and engineering for Foursquare, [Pinterest](http://www.quora.com/Pinterest/What-technologies-were-used-to-make-Pinterest/answer/Paul-Sciarra), and [Instagram](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/13649370142/what-powers-instagram-hundreds-of-instances-dozens-of). I can only find [MongoDB links about Foursquare](http://www.10gen.com/customers/foursquare) but you get the idea. You might look more deeply into the [Amazon AWS tutorials](http://aws.amazon.com/architecture/) for your own use.

Comment: @Mxx I'm using because I get so much traffic that a single server can't handle it... :-(

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening on Linux, why not write a bash script to recieve events from inotify (using inotify-tools) then rsync them around?

inotify-tools: https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/

They actually have some examples on that page that do pretty much what I described.